# What are the plugin, dependencies to generate reports by using Selenium, JUNIT, MAVEN

Tags: maven, ant, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am setting up selenium maven project by using Selenium webdriver,JUNIT,MAVEN.

So in pom.xml I have given selenium related dependencies.. What are all the plug in and dependencies to generate Junit reports?

Comment: Please see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>  <reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputName>MavenSeleniumTestResults</outputName>                   
    </configuration>
  </plugin> 

</plugins>
```

Comment: If I use driver.close(); in code and if I install by using commands like mvn install I am facing error                                     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project DARTMavenSelenium: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\D888977\workspace\DARTMavenSelenium\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]